# ListActivity with bottom button

Tags: android-layout

Hi I've created a listActivity which contain some rows of data and at the bottom of the screen (not the list) I've put a button.My problem is that in case that my list is full ,and therefore needs to be scrolled in order for the other rows to be seen,the button seems to be transparent and overlapping the last element of the list.So it doesn't seem pleasant to the  eye.Do you have any suggestion of how to fix such problem?is there any way for my list to leave some space for the bottom button?I wouldn't like to implement it with footer view.I'll post the xml file so that you can have a clearer picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <DragNDrop.DragNDropListView
      android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
  </DragNDrop.DragNDropListView>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:alpha="1"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
      android:text="Return" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:alpha="1"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
      android:text="Return" />

  <DragNDrop.DragNDropListView
      android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_above="@id/btn" >
  </DragNDrop.DragNDropListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In a RelativeLayout, elements are placed on the top left corner by default, there's no need to specify that for the List

Comment: ok I tried everything this seems to be working as i wanted many thanks to everyone for your answers and time

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `LinearLayout` with `orientation = vertical` and `ListView` with `layout_weight = 1` and Button below the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Put the button first in the relative layout and then set attribute

```
android:layout_above="@id/btn"
```

to list view. So the last elements will not be discovered by the button because the height of the list is max height minus button height.

Answer (score 1):

change your xml as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<DragNDrop.DragNDropListView
  android:id="@+id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_above="@id/btn"
  android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
  android:layout_weight="1" >
 </DragNDrop.DragNDropListView>

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:alpha="1"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
  android:text="Return" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, in this way you will have 10% for the button in the whole view, and 90% for the list view and the button will not overlap the last list element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="100" >

 <ListView
  android:id="@+id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="90" >
</ListView>

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="10"
  android:text="Return" />

</LinearLayout>
```